# CSS: How to select all rel atributes

Tags: css, css-selectors, rel

Every time an image is uploaded in wordpress, it receives a different rel atribute, for example rel="attachment name123", and I want to select every image with a rel atribute, regardless of their name. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
 Actually they are links  so thanks to the answers the correct way to select links is:

```
a[rel] {pointer-events: none; cursor: default;}
```

That's for removing the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all images with a rel attribute defined by:

```
img[rel] {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This selector should work: `img[rel]`.

According to [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

> 5.8 Attribute selectors
>
> CSS 2.1 allows authors to specify rules that match elements which have
>   certain attributes defined in the source document.
>
> 5.8.1 Matching attributes and attribute values
>
> Attribute selectors may match in four ways:
>
> [att] **Match when the element sets the "att" attribute, whatever the
>   value of the attribute.**

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uePqg/).